# Letting a user use a compiled RequireJS Widget after it has loaded

Tags: asynchronous, requirejs, javascript

I'm writing a JS Widget using RequireJS. After finishing the widget I'm compiling it with r.js and Almond. All goes well - but I couldn't find an easy way to let the user use the widget without using RequireJS himself - as the widget code loads async (RequireJS uses AMD).

What I'm doing now is busy waiting for the widget code to load and using it only after detecting it has loaded. This is not very user-friendly.

Is there a way to let just do something like this?

```
var widget = new Widget();
```

instead of doing busy wait like:

```
count = 0;

function loadWidget() {
    if (typeof Widget != 'undefined') {
        var p1 = new Widget();
        p1.render();
    } else {
        if (count > 10) {
            console.log('Failed to load the Widget');
            return false;
        }
        setTimeout(loadWidget, 50);
        count++;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    loadWidget();
});
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

my build.js

```
({
    name: './lib/almond.js',
    out: './deploy/sdk.min.js',
    baseUrl: '.',
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    mainConfigFile: 'sdk.js',
    include: ['sdk'],
    wrap: true
})
```

Code on the web page (assume no other script tags on page):

```
<script src="mywidget.js" data-main="scripts/sdk" id="mywidget"></script>
```

No sure if the 'data-main' is really required as the js is compiled.

Comment: hm.. why not to use standard requirejs workflow - define Widget as AMD module, include on page main require file and inside it request Widget ?

Comment: I don't want to make the user use RequireJS - thus I compile the widget into one JS file for consumption.

Comment: your comment made issue more stranger ) in title of your question you mentioned you want to let user use RequireJS, in question body you also mentioned you develop Widget with RequireJS and in comment text you mentioned opposite.. Please add some details in your question or rephrase it

Comment: Thank you - I changed the title to make it more clear.

Comment: Please show us the build configuration you pass to `r.js` and how you load your widget in a web page.

Comment: @Louis - I've added the build config. The usage inside the web page is already shown - it's the 'loadWidget' code that I'd like to make only 'new Widget()' instead of the busy wait I'm using.

Comment: @Roman, show how you **load** your widget in a web page. That's done with a `script` element and/or by calling `require` somewhere. In what you show there is no `script` element nor is there a call to `require`.

Comment: @Louis - Done :) And there is no RequireJS as this should be a standalone widget compiled with Almond (minimum version for RequireJS for compiling RequireJS code). The compilation is of course with r.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions provided with [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond#exporting-a-public-api). To summarize the essential points what is in the doc there, what you need in your build config the following configuration:

```
wrap: {
    startFile: 'path/to/start.frag',
    endFile: 'path/to/end.frag'
}
```

And the `start.frag` should be:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else {
        root.Widget = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
```

and the `end.frag`:

```
    return require('main');
}));
```

The end fragment calls `require` in its synchronous form, which is **really** synchronous in this case (and not the pseudo-synchronous sugar that can be used by RequrieJS itself).

I've tried this before. It works.

Comment: Thanks @Louis - I've managed to compile this, but can't locate the 'Widget' in anyplace - how would you use it? (How would you do 'var p = new Widget()'? Widget doesn't seem to be available

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `root.Widget = factory()` does the debugger stop there?

Comment: Yes it does :/ After removing the uglify2 optimization

Comment: The line is run but root.Widget gets 'undefined' value

Comment: How does your `main` module export `Widget`?

Comment: In the `main.js` I have a `define` Which just requires all the dependencies and does nothing. Should it export it somehow?

Comment: Yes, your module should export `Widget`. It's one of the reasons to use RequireJS: having a clean way to export **only** what you want to export and not pollute the global space. You could use `return Widget` inside your module, for instance. See the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) for all the ways you can export values.